# How to pass nvarchar (non-English) to CLR (C#) stored procedure?

Tags: .net, stored-procedures, sqlclr, sqlxml, non-english

Working in Visual Studio, I'm trying to pass an entire row to a CLR stored procedure using FOR XML RAW and a parameter of type SqlXml in C# code (with the intent of processing the row using XmlReader). The row contains nvarchar fields.

Everything works correctly when the nvarchar fields contain English/numeric/simple punctuation text, but when any of them contain Hebrew or Russian characters, these characters are turned into question marks. (The same for Russian-only text so not an RTL issue)

From prints in SQL code I've found that the xml created by XML RAW preserves the non-English characters - they are printed just fine. But when printing sqlXmlParameter.Value (or putting it in output string and printing that in sql) question marks are printed instead of the non-English characters.
I've tried using an SqlString parameter and got the same result - the parameter looks fine in SQL, but changes when passed to CLR procedure.

I've also found that both T-SQL and C# use UTF-16 as default encoding, so this is really weird.

How can I preserve non-English characters when passing parameters to CLR, or attach encoding information to them?

Edit: This Question relates to the following: [How to make SqlContext.Pipe.Send in SQLCLR stored proc work with unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36965984/how-to-make-sqlcontext-pipe-send-in-sqlclr-stored-proc-work-with-unicode)
As it turns out, the solution to the other question solved this issue as well. I'm not sure why, since the C# code in this case contained no non-English characters, but it did use string formatting with strings that could be non-English, so maybe some mix of encodings was caused because of how the constants in the string format were saved. Just my guess though.
So in case someone runs into a related problem (despite my vague definition of it) you might want to try that.

Comment: How do you transfer the XML from RDBMS to your application?

Comment: @Shnugo I added the C# code as stored procedure and called the stored procedure from SQL. As far as I can tell VS turned the C# code into an assembly and automatically created stored procedures that call that assembly AS EXTERNAL.

Comment: Yes, by default, strings in Windows / .NET / SQL Server ( `NVARCHAR` / `NCHAR` / `XML` ) are UTF-16 Little Endian. There should be no changing of characters when transferring from XML from SQL Server into a SQLCLR object, whether into `SqlXml` or `SqlString` / `SqlChars`. Have you tried `SqlChars`, which gives you a `char[]`? You can create a new string from it: `string _Test = new string(SqlCharsParam.Value);`.

Comment: You might post some code? I've seen strange implicit conversions in connection with string manipulations people (e.g. when adding a root node or a top level processing instruction (`<?  somthing ?>`) or when combining XML parts...

Comment: Also, what is the LCID of Windows and the LCID of the database containing the SQLCLR code? Run the following: `SELECT os_language_version,
       DATABASEPROPERTYEX(N'{name of DB where Assembly exists}', 'LCID') AS 'DatabaseLCID'
FROM   sys.dm_os_windows_info;`

Comment: And, how are you passing the value into the SQLCLR Stored Procedure? Are you using an `XML` variable, `NVARCHAR` variable, or `VARCHAR` variable? Or a string literal? You should only be dealing with `XML` / `NVARCHAR` datatypes and prefixing literals with `N`.

Comment: @strutzky LCID is 1033 - US English. Am I supposed to change it to one of the languages causing problems? I need to support tables with both...

Comment: @strutzky on the SQL side the datatype is XML for SqlXml and nvarchar for SqlString.

Comment: I can't really help until you answer _all_ of my questions, including the LCID of _both_ the DB and the OS using the supplied query, and test with `SqlChars`. Also, I won't get notified of your response if you misspell my login. Just type `@` and the first letter or two and it should auto-suggest the rest.

Answer (score 0):

No example code has been provided (the C# or even the T-SQL to call the Stored Procedure) so it is hard to say for certain, but you are probably making a mistake in how you are calling the Stored Procedure. Most likely you are not prefixing the Unicode and XML literals with an `N` to keep them as Unicode. The following C# code and T-SQL show that SQLCLR does properly accept and display Unicode characters across all three datatypes: `SqlString`, `SqlChars`, and `SqlXml` (sample Hebrew and Russian text taken from your related Question):

**C#**

```cs
using System;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

public class UnicodeTesting
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
    public static void PrintTest(SqlString StringParam, SqlChars CharsParam,
                                 SqlXml XmlParam)
    {
        SqlContext.Pipe.Send("Unicode test: blip");
        SqlContext.Pipe.Send("Unicode test: בליפ");
        SqlContext.Pipe.Send("Unicode test: Блип");

        SqlContext.Pipe.Send("StringParam: " + StringParam.Value);
        SqlContext.Pipe.Send("CharsParam: " + new String(CharsParam.Value));
        SqlContext.Pipe.Send("XmlParam: " + XmlParam.Value);
    }
}
```

**T-SQL**

```sql
EXEC dbo.PrintTest N'בליפ a',
                   N'בליפ b',
                   N'<test>בליפ c</test><test>Блип</test>';
```

**Output (in "Messages" tab)**

```
Unicode test: blip
Unicode test: בליפ
Unicode test: Блип
StringParam: בליפ a
CharsParam: בליפ b
XmlParam: <test>בליפ c</test><test>Блип</test>
```

Comment: I pass the result of FOR XML as stored procedure parameter and the parameter is of type XML, so I can't append N' directly to that. When I print the resulting xml for debugging, the non-English appears fine. Server is down atm but I could try sending it as nvarchar instead to see if it helps (would add some conversion overhead).

Comment: @MASQ You still are being too vague for me to really help. I know that the parameter is XML, but you are obviously storing the result of the FOR XML in a variable first. You need to update the Question with the T-SQL that you are using to generate the XML and call the SQLCLR Stored Procedure.

Comment: Uh, I'm just kinda new at my job and not sure what the policy is about other people's code (or any). I was going to post an edited code sample but looks like changing the save settings on the C# code (from your answer on my other question) somehow solved this.

Comment: @MASQ I don't need the C# code (at least most likely not). I just need the T-SQL that you are testing with. The script that does the FOR XML and calls the Stored Procedure. I can't see why changing the encoding of the **.cs** file would alter the behavior described in this Question. Either way, it would be good to get to the bottom of this one to document it for others.

Comment: I'd like to know why it made a difference too, but that was definitely the only change to the original code (others were done in separate projects). I read SqlXml with XmlReader, copy parts of it into strings, and then make and execute SqlCommands from string formatting using those strings. The literals in the string formatting do not contain non-English characters. When there's non-English coming in from the Xml, it gets mixed with string literals in formatting, I thought maybe it conforms to the literal's encoding which may be ascii or whatever the save default is.

Comment: Now that debugging using SQL pipe works properly, as far as I can the T-SQL part worked fine all along.

Comment: There is no encoding of literals in .NET code. Strings are inherently UTF-16 Little Endian. And the encoding of the source code file doesn't usually matter. Most of my .cs files are Windows 1252 since I don't usually use characters outside of that range. Are you sure that you were printing out the values being passed in and not literals from within the .cs file when you created this question? I can't see any possible way to print out `SqlString.Value` or `SqlXml.Value` that could alter the characters.

Comment: I don't remember about printing, that might have been a different mistake, I mean a situation like the following:
`string s = Format("some text {0} more text", var.Value);`
where this code (and therefore string literal) is saved in a file with Windows 1252 encoding but var might contain a Unicode string?