# How to make SqlContext.Pipe.Send in SQLCLR stored proc work with unicode?

Tags: .net, sql-server, unicode, character-encoding, sqlclr

I'm having problems with SQL CLR integration with unicode (Hebrew and Russian text). As a test, I made a simple database project in Visual Studio with the following CLR stored procedure:

```cs
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
public static void TestProc ()
{
    //Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
    Trace.WriteLine("Unicode test: blip");
    Trace.WriteLine("Unicode test: בליפ");
    Trace.WriteLine("Unicode test: Блип");
    SqlContext.Pipe.Send("Unicode test: blip");
    SqlContext.Pipe.Send("Unicode test: בליפ");
    SqlContext.Pipe.Send("Unicode test: Блип");
}
```

Published to a test database and executed the stored procedure in SQL server:

```sql
EXEC dbo.TestProc;
```

Both the trace output and SQL server messages replace non-English characters with '????'.

I thought both SQL server and C# worked with unicode. Working with unicode in a Windows Forms project, for example by adding non-English text to a textbox, works fine.

How can I fix this? Is there some setting I'm missing?

This Question relates to the following: [How to pass nvarchar (non-English) to CLR (C#) stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36915616/how-to-pass-nvarchar-non-english-to-clr-c-stored-procedure)

Comment: I tested with your code and also got the "????" for the Hebrew and Russian, even if I changed the database's default Collation to `Hebrew_100_CI_AS` (which shouldn't be necessary, but just to test with). I will look at this more tomorrow.

Comment: Oh, in case it's relevant, I also tried sending strings that contained nothing but Hebrew characters / nothing but Russian and got all ????, so the issue is not in mixing different codepages (I don't know if that's a thing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing that while doing this test, you never closed and re-opened the tab containing the **.cs** file. Is that correct? You see, Visual Studio doesn't compile the code in the editor, it compiles the code that is saved in the file that you might be currently editing. Those are usually 100% the same, BUT when it comes to "characters" based on values above 127, then Code Pages / Encodings become important. And to be clear, we are talking about the Encoding / Code Page of the C# file, *not* of the Database.

The problem is that the default encoding, at least on my system and I suspect on most within the United States, is "Windows 1252". So what is happening is that when you compile this code into the Assembly, what is in your editor is saved to disk. But the file encoding cannot support those characters, hence they get turned into `?` *in the C# file* ! Yes, the code getting compiled is *not* what you are seeing on screen. But you would see it if you were to close the **.cs** file and re-open it. Both the Hebrew and Russian text would be all `?`s. And that is what SQL Server is being asked to print.

To fix this, just go to the **File** menu, select **Advanced Save Options...** and in the top drop-down for **Encoding**, select either:

- Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001

  or:
- Unicode - Codepage 1200   [ this one should save as UTF-16 Little Endian ]

Replace the `?` with the intended Hebrew and Russian characters. Now you can Build and Publish and have those characters display as intended.

Comment: You're right, as soon as I closed and reopened all the non-English characters within the code itself turned into ????. Using advanced save options did fix what SQL was printing. Trace is still printing ????, but that might have more to do with DebugViewer settings, and the important thing is I know C# can send the correct characters to SQL and can debug non-English strings.